# how to display xml atribute with jquery (within zRSSFeed script)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, rss

This is a snippet of the xml file from an RSS feed

```
<item>
<title>creamy whites</title>
<description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="/pin/201606520789168653/"&gt;&lt;img 
src="http://media-cache.pinterest.com/upload/229261437250994034_0HxSxJNv_b.jpg"
&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;creamy whites&lt;/p&gt;</description>
</item>
```

Now this is the code that is already in the ZRRSfeed:

```
// Add feed row
html += '<li class="rssRow '+row+'">' + 
    '<'+ options.titletag +'><a href="'+ entry.link +'" title="'+          
        feeds.title +'" target="'+ options.linktarget +'">'
        + entry.description +'</a></'+ 
        options.titletag +'>'
```

Now instead of getting the `entry.decription` I would like to get the `src` value that is within the `entry.decription`
I have tried: 
`entry.decription[src]`, `entry.decription[src].val()`, `entry.decription->src` `entry.decription.attr(src)`, `entry.decription.getAtrribute("src")` (i might have mis-typed any of this code here - but when I tried them I did check in google for things like 'getAttribute') and none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

try this one..

```
var src = $('entry.description')find('img').attr('src');

console.log(src); // debug using console firebug in firefox
//or developer tools in chrome
//the output should be the url of img
```

then replace entry.description that lies within anchor tag with src.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(entry.description).find('img').attr('src')
```

Comment: that is not working. The output is 'undefined' - no errors come up. Thanks